# What could cause FFT data to have spikes at the wrong frequencies?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm implementing FFT pitch detection on the iPhone using Apple's Accelerate framework as discussed [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633203) here before.

I understand phase offsets, bin frequencies, and have researched several open-source tuners that use FFT techniques (simple pitch detection, autocorrelation, cepstrum, and the like) to detect pitch. Here's my problem:

**My FFT results are consistently off by 5-10 Hz (+/-), even when the bins are only 1-2 hertz apart.** I've tried different algorithms, and even a simple FFT sampled at high resolution shows the magnitude spikes in seemingly the wrong places. It's not a consistent offset; some are too high, some too low.

For instance, a 440Hz tone comes across as 445.2 Hz; a 220Hz as 214Hz; an 880Hz as 874Hz; 1174Hz as 1183Hz using a tone generator. A similar [open-source tuner](http://code.google.com/p/ctuner/source/browse/trunk/mac/Tuner.c) for Mac using almost exactly the same algorithms has no problem detecting the pitch perfectly. (These differences are different when on the device than the simulator, but they are still off.)

I don't think the problem is bin resolution, because there are often a few bins between the actual tone and the detected magnitude spike. It's as though the input is just hearing the wrong pitch.

I've pasted my code below. The general flow is simple:

Push a step onto the FFT buffer -> Hann Window -> FFT -> Phase/Magnitude -> Max pitch is wrong.

```
enum {
    kOversample = 4,
    kSamples = MAX_FRAME_LENGTH,
    kSamples2 = kSamples / 2,
    kRange = kSamples * 5 / 16,
    kStep = kSamples / kOversample
};



const int PENDING_LEN = kSamples * 5;
static float pendingAudio[PENDING_LEN * sizeof(float)];
static int pendingAudioLength = 0;

- (void)processBuffer {
    static float window[kSamples];
    static float phase[kRange];
    static float lastPhase[kRange];
    static float phaseDeltas[kRange];
    static float frequencies[kRange];
    static float slidingFFTBuffer[kSamples];
    static float buffer[kSamples];

    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if (!initialized) {
        memset(lastPhase, 0, kRange * sizeof(float));

        vDSP_hann_window(window, kSamples, 0);
        initialized = YES;
    }

    BOOL canProcessNewStep = YES;
    while (canProcessNewStep) {        

        @synchronized (self) {
            if (pendingAudioLength < kStep) {
                break; // not enough data
            }            
            // Rotate one step's worth of pendingAudio onto the end of slidingFFTBuffer
            memmove(slidingFFTBuffer, slidingFFTBuffer + kStep, (kSamples - kStep) * sizeof(float));
            memmove(slidingFFTBuffer + (kSamples - kStep), pendingAudio, kStep * sizeof(float));
            memmove(pendingAudio, pendingAudio + kStep, (PENDING_LEN - kStep) * sizeof(float));
            pendingAudioLength -= kStep;   
            canProcessNewStep = (pendingAudioLength >= kStep);
        }

        // Hann Windowing
        vDSP_vmul(slidingFFTBuffer, 1, window, 1, buffer, 1, kSamples);      
        vDSP_ctoz((COMPLEX *)buffer, 2, &splitComplex, 1, kSamples2);        

        // Carry out a Forward FFT transform.
        vDSP_fft_zrip(fftSetup, &splitComplex, 1, log2f(kSamples), FFT_FORWARD);        

        // magnitude to decibels
        static float magnitudes[kRange];        
        vDSP_zvmags(&splitComplex, 1, magnitudes, 1, kRange);        
        float zero = 1.0;
        vDSP_vdbcon(magnitudes, 1, &zero, magnitudes, 1, kRange, 0); // to decibels

        // phase
        vDSP_zvphas(&splitComplex, 1, phase, 1, kRange); // compute magnitude and phase        
        vDSP_vsub(lastPhase, 1, phase, 1, phaseDeltas, 1, kRange); // compute phase difference
        memcpy(lastPhase, phase, kRange * sizeof(float)); // save old phase

        double freqPerBin = sampleRate / (double)kSamples;
        double phaseStep = 2.0 * M_PI * (float)kStep / (float)kSamples;

        // process phase difference ( via https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4633203 )
        for (int k = 1; k < kRange; k++) {
            double delta = phaseDeltas[k];
            delta -= k * phaseStep;  // subtract expected phase difference
            delta = remainder(delta, 2.0 * M_PI);  // map delta phase into +/- M_PI interval
            delta /= phaseStep;  // calculate diff from bin center frequency
            frequencies[k] = (k + delta) * freqPerBin;  // calculate the true frequency
        }               

        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        MCTunerData *tunerData = [[[MCTunerData alloc] initWithSize:MAX_FRAME_LENGTH] autorelease];        

        double maxMag = -INFINITY;
        float maxFreq = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < kRange; i++) {
            [tunerData addFrequency:frequencies[i] withMagnitude:magnitudes[i]];
            if (magnitudes[i] > maxMag) {
                maxFreq = frequencies[i];
                maxMag = magnitudes[i];
            }
        }

        NSLog(@"Max Frequency: %.1f", maxFreq);

        [tunerData calculate];

        // Update the UI with our newly acquired frequency value.
        [self.delegate frequencyChangedWithValue:[tunerData mainFrequency] data:tunerData];

        [pool drain];
    }

}

OSStatus renderCallback(void *inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags, 
                       const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, 
                       AudioBufferList *ioData)
{
    MCTuner* tuner = (MCTuner *)inRefCon;    

    OSStatus err = AudioUnitRender(tuner->audioUnit, ioActionFlags, inTimeStamp, 1, inNumberFrames, tuner->bufferList);
    if (err < 0) {
        return err;
    }

    // convert SInt16 to float because iOS doesn't support recording floats directly
    SInt16 *inputInts = (SInt16 *)tuner->bufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;

    @synchronized (tuner) {
        if (pendingAudioLength + inNumberFrames < PENDING_LEN) {

            // Append the audio that just came in into the pending audio buffer, converting to float
            // because iOS doesn't support recording floats directly
            for(int i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) {
                pendingAudio[pendingAudioLength + i] = (inputInts[i] + 0.5) / 32767.5;
            }
            pendingAudioLength += inNumberFrames;
        } else {
            // the buffer got too far behind. Don't give any more audio data.
            NSLog(@"Dropping frames...");
        }
        if (pendingAudioLength >= kStep) {
            [tuner performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(processBuffer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        }
    }

    return noErr;
}
```

Comment: would you mind to explain how the main frequency is being calculated in [tunerData calculate] & [tunerData mainFrequency]? Is the value of mainFrequency differs from maxFreq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confident that it wasn't actually anything in my algorithm; rather, something was wrong with my use of Apple's AUGraph. When I removed that to just use a plain Audio Unit without setting up a graph, I was able to get it to recognize the pitch properly.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't gone through your code in detail, but this jumped right out at me:

```
vDSP_zvmags(&splitComplex, 1, magnitudes, 1, kRange);
```

It's important to remember that the result of a real-to-complex fft comes packed in a somewhat odd layout.  If the real and imaginary parts of the jth fourier coefficient are denoted by R(j) and I(j), the `real` and `imag` components of the `splitComplex` object have the following contents:

```
.real = {  R(0) , R(1), R(2), ... , R(n/2 - 1) } 
.imag = { R(n/2), I(1), I(2), ... , I(n/2 - 1) }
```

Thus, your magnitude calculation is doing something a little weird; the first entry in your magnitude vector is `sqrt(R(0)^2 + R(n/2)^2)`, where it should just be `|R(0)|`.  I didn't carefully study all the constants, but it seems likely that this is leading to an off-by-one error where you lose the nyquist band (`R(n/2)`) or similar.  An off-by-one error of that sort is likely to result in the frequency bands being viewed as just a little wider or narrower than they really are, which would result in a small pitch scaling up or down over the whole range, which matches what you're seeing.

Answer (score 1):

The FFT is a chainsaw, not a scalpel.
In general, to reality-check FFT coding, (1) test using Parseval's theorem (mean squared amplitude in time domain should within roundoff equal the sum of your spectrum) and (2) inverse FFT and just listen to it.
Sorry, but you seem to be expecting too much absolute accuracy from the fft. You're simply not going to get it. There is, however, a checklist of little things to check in your code. Most algos move DC and Nyquist to make memory allocations come up even, but you must manually move the Nyquist term where it belongs and true-zero out various things:

```
A.realp[NOVER2] = A.imagp[0];   // move real Nyquist term to where it belongs
A.imagp[NOVER2] = 0.0;          // this is zero
A.imagp[0] = 0.0;               // make this a true zero
```

On audio data, DC should be zero (e.g., amplitudes have zero-mean), but in small windows, it may not be. I leave it alone.
You are doing much more than you need to to find the max bin (comment about phase vocoder is correct). IMHO using a hamm window hurts accuracy. I have much better results padding the end of the real data with *lots* (4x) of zeros. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using not just an FFT, but a phase vocoder after the FFT to adjust the estimated bin frequencies.  Depending on the phase gain and limits, phase vocoder frequency adjustments can pull an estimated frequency well outside of the FFT bin width.  If this is happening, using narrower bins (a longer FFT) won't help.  You might want to do a sanity check to see if you want peak frequencies pulled outside of their FFT frequency bins.  Or try taking out the phase vocoder to see if the FFT alone returns more sane results.

Comment: Taking out the phase vocodor, unfortunately, produces similar results (still off).