# Flange/Echo/Reverb effect in iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, audio

I want to apply Flange/Echo/Reverb effect on the audio file that is saved in the documents directory in iphone. I have been searching internet for this since a long time but no luck. Can someone please suggest me the way to implement these effects in iphone ??

Answer (score 8):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9444596/1648976 for reverb

```
 AudioComponentDescription auEffectUnitDescription;
 auEffectUnitDescription.componentType = kAudioUnitType_Effect;
 auEffectUnitDescription.componentSubType = kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2;
 auEffectUnitDescription.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple;

AUGraphAddNode(
                          processingGraph,
                          &auEffectUnitDescription,
                          &auEffectNode),
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html

These are the options in the link up here

Effect Audio Unit Subtypes
Effect (digital signal processing) audio unit subtypes for audio units provided by Apple.

```
enum {
kAudioUnitSubType_PeakLimiter          = 'lmtr',
kAudioUnitSubType_DynamicsProcessor    = 'dcmp',
kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2              = 'rvb2',
kAudioUnitSubType_LowPassFilter        = 'lpas',
kAudioUnitSubType_BandPassFilter       = 'bpas',
kAudioUnitSubType_HighShelfFilter      = 'hshf',
kAudioUnitSubType_LowShelfFilter       = 'lshf',
kAudioUnitSubType_ParametricEQ         = 'pmeq',
kAudioUnitSubType_Delay                = 'dely',
kAudioUnitSubType_Distortion           = 'dist',
kAudioUnitSubType_AUiPodEQ             = 'ipeq',
kAudioUnitSubType_NBandEQ              = 'nbeq'
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please share some link of the Sample codes that utilise this thing..

Comment: Sorry, i dont have time to do so. Maybe you could google for kAudioUnitSubType_Reverb2 tutorial

Comment: If this answer helped you, feel free to accept is as answer.. or reward me with a +1