# How do I set up a buffer when doing an FFT using the Accelerate framework?

Tags: iphone, cocoa, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm using the Accelerate framework to perform a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT), and am trying to find a way to create a buffer for use with it that has a length of 1024.  I have access to the average peak and peak of a signal on which I want to do the FFT.

Can somebody help me or give me some hints to do this?

Comment: In one of WWDC2010 sessions about Accelerate.Framework they spoke about that. I might be wrong but *probably* there is a sample about that. Either way, you should look at Accelerate.Framework reference, there are very useful functions for doing what you want ;)

Comment: You might want to look at the answers to [this StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework "this stack overflow question"). A number of good examples are provided of using Apple's Accelerate framework to generate an FFT of audio.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apple has some examples of how to set up FFTs in their [vDSP Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  You should also check out the [vDSP Examples](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/vDSPExamples/Introduction/Intro.html) sample application.  While for the Mac, this code should translate directly across to iOS as well.

I recently needed to do a simple FFT of an 64 integer input waveform, for which I used the following code:

```
static FFTSetupD fft_weights;
static DSPDoubleSplitComplex input;
static double *magnitudes;

+ (void)initialize
{
    /* Setup weights (twiddle factors) */
    fft_weights = vDSP_create_fftsetupD(6, kFFTRadix2);

    /* Allocate memory to store split-complex input and output data */
    input.realp = (double *)malloc(64 * sizeof(double));
    input.imagp = (double *)malloc(64 * sizeof(double));
    magnitudes = (double *)malloc(64 * sizeof(double));
}

- (CGFloat)performAcceleratedFastFourierTransformAndReturnMaximumAmplitudeForArray:(NSUInteger *)waveformArray;
{   
    for (NSUInteger currentInputSampleIndex = 0; currentInputSampleIndex < 64; currentInputSampleIndex++)
    {
        input.realp[currentInputSampleIndex] = (double)waveformArray[currentInputSampleIndex];
        input.imagp[currentInputSampleIndex] = 0.0f;
    }

    /* 1D in-place complex FFT */
    vDSP_fft_zipD(fft_weights, &input, 1, 6, FFT_FORWARD);  

    input.realp[0] = 0.0;
    input.imagp[0] = 0.0;

    // Get magnitudes
    vDSP_zvmagsD(&input, 1, magnitudes, 1, 64);

    // Extract the maximum value and its index
    double fftMax = 0.0;
    vDSP_maxmgvD(magnitudes, 1, &fftMax, 64);

    return sqrt(fftMax);
}
```

As you can see, I only used the real values in this FFT to set up the input buffers, performed the FFT, and then read out the magnitudes.

Comment: Thanks - this is a much simpler example than others I have seen (where they mostly perform an inverse FFT straight after). Very helpful as I could see which are the minimum bits I needed for my problem!

Comment: You put just wave amplitude indexes to real values. Should imagp be zero? It is not clear for me. Why are you not using CTOZ function? thx

Comment: @SergeyKopanev He uses a complex to complex fft (and not a real to complex fft). In this case you don't need to arrange the real data since all of them will be stored in the realp array of the  `DSPDoubleSplitComplex`. The imaginary array will be empty since the there is no imaginary values.