# What logic is used for creating an Equalizer meter

Tags: ios, pseudocode, audio-player

Basically i'm gonna be working on an iOS music app which when a song is being played, it shows the fancy Equalizer meter, Something like this but with all the animation of bars going up and down:

[image: Equalizer meter]

After looking into this and not finding enough resource, I really want to carry this as a project perhaps making a web version using j query.

I'm not really asking for specific code, i just want to know how the animation works in general ?

Thanks a million !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checkout the [Cocoa Waveform Audio Player Control](https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform) project. It's a cocoa audio player component which displays the waveform of the audio file.

Also, there is already a lot of questions on this topic:

[iOS FFT Accerelate.framework draw spectrum during playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636134/ios-fft-accerelate-framework-draw-spectrum-during-playback?rq=1)

[Using the Apple FFT and Accelerate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework?lq=1)

[iOS FFT Draw spectrum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568607/ios-fft-draw-spectrum?rq=1)

Animation would be pretty straight forward. It is just animating changes of the height of rectangles.