How to identify an specific Beep frequency on audio files (.Wav, .Mp3)?
I have a problem where I have a dataset of audio's files, and I need to cut every single of it in 2 pieces: one piece after and one before a determined "beep" sound.
I examined some audios for example, on the Audacity tool, and I found out that the beep sound occours at a 425Hz frequency, screnshoots below.


First, I tried using this DtmfDetection function, without any success. I used the default config, changing the threshold only. It doest work;
var mycfg = new Config(threshold: 425, sampleBlockSize: 205, sampleRate: 8000, normalizeResponse: false);

Then, I used NAudio to get a numeric array from an audio file, and it brings me a value between -1 and 1 for each position (Amplitude column on screnshoot below). This array contains 10.000 positions for each second of the real audio. So every position means 0,1 miliseconds of audio.
I used this Fast_Fourier_Transform tool to plot my numeric array, and it loks correct. If I plot my array there, the image looks like expected for the original audio.
I just dont know how to proced now. The beep sound last for like 0.8 seconds, what should be the my next steps to obtain, the time that the beep occours on the audio file? Any suggestions?


If beep stand out clearly (like on screenshot), you can use aplitudes array to find the time when it starts/ends, just find a piece of array where ABS(amplitude[i]) > min and test if it's a beep. Otherwise you need to split amplitudes in smaller chunks and test each. The beep test looks like FFT conversion of that peice/chunk and comparing its maximum dominant frequency with that of beep signal.

You need to extract a window of the samples from the audio for FFT, and then analyze which parts have values at 425 Hz that exceed the threshold. Combined with the amplitude in the time domain, you can determine which period of time contains waves at 425 Hz continuously.

I was thinking about something like that, but I dont know EXACTLY what to do. The tool Im using has a FFT funcion. I used it on the sample amplitude array I showed as example, and it generated this output: https://imgur.com/a/pO28lh3 . What I am looking for exaclty? Columns with Frequency ~0,425x Hz right? Then which value tell me the occurrence? (Magnitude, Phase, Real, Img)

Magnitude https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636698/6196568

One approach that doesn't require doing transforms to the frequency domain would be using a cross correlation. Assuming the beep is identical (in length, frequency, waveshape) for each audio file, you can cut out the beep in audacity and convert that to an array using NAudio. Plotting the cross correlation between that array and each file in your dataset will produce a large spike where the beep occurs. You can use the index of that spike as the location to split the file
