# Transform discrete data to continuous

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

I'm writing a program that has, as one facet, a wave filtration/resolution routine. The more data I collect, the bigger the files stored to the device get. I'm collecting data at discrete time steps, and in the interest of accuracy I'm doing this pretty frequently. However, I noticed that the overall wave form tends to be wide enough that I could be collecting data at about half the rate I am and still be able to draw an accurate-enough-for-my-purposes waveform over the data.

So the question: is there a way to, from this data, create a continuous mathematic description of the curve? I haven't been able to find anything. My data is `float` inside of `NSNumbers` contained by an `NSArray`.

The two things I would like to be able to do are get intersections points for a threshold and find local maximums. The ability to do either one of these would be sufficient.

**-EDIT-**

If anyone knows a good objective-c FFT method for 1-dimensional real arrays I would love to hear it.

Comment: You need some knowledge on Digital signal processing.

Comment: @luyuan I've done digital signal processing before, just not with objective-c (only matlab and python)

Comment: Then you can transform the discrete date from time domain into frequency domain. Do you know FFT?

Comment: Not in xcode... matlab had a function for it, but I haven't been able to find any good examples for 1-d real arrays in objective-c.

Comment: search for it. As i haven't done it in xcode too:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple includes an FFT in the Accelerate framework.

[Using Fourier Transforms](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/UsingFourierTransforms/UsingFourierTransforms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH202-SW1)

Example: [FFT Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/vDSP_Programming_Guide/SampleCode/SampleCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005147-CH205-45465)

Also: [Using the Apple FFT and Accelerate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework)

Comment: I saw this one, but I haven't been able to get it to work  for for 1-D real arrays. Is there an example anywhere? I'm coming from matlab where I could do fft(array) and be done.

Comment: Thanks, the apple docs for the accelerate framework were completely incomprehensible.