# Setting up a spectrum analyser in iPhone using Accelerate framework

Tags: iphone, ios, signal-processing, core-audio, fft

How to set up a spectrum analyser for an audio file?

I understand that i must get the data, and then apply a FFT and then show the spectrum analyser for the frequencies.

But how to get the data? of the playing audio file? Should I use the AudioQueue service to get the data via the call back ? And then use the data from the obtained call back to apply Fast Fourier transform? how to apply fast Fourier transform in a simple way to suit my needs

I read this post [Using the Apple FFT and Accelerate Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework)

but still require lot of clarifications, and cannot find any documentation clear enough

Comment: Hi Paul! Did u find the answer ? We are still looking for... Thx.