# BPM detection in iOS

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

Is there any way to do BPM detection that anyone knows of inside cocos2d or directc?  Does that, as a concept, even make sense?  I'm wondering why I've never seen any mp3 visualizers on iPad.

Comment: BPM = Beat per Minute ?

Comment: you haven't? https://www.google.de/search?q=ios+visualizer&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en&client=safari#sclient=tablet-gws&client=safari&hl=en&q=iphone+music+visualizer&oq=iphone+visualizer&gs_l=tablet-gws.1.1.0i20j0i7l2.6476.9796.0.12014.9.9.0.0.0.4.1362.4807.0j4j2j7-3.9.0....0...1c.1.19.tablet-gws-psy.k8EgHy2y58M&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.&bvm=bv.48705608,d.ZWU&fp=2f765a3316267054&biw=768&bih=928

Comment: and here's how to do it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework?lq=1

Comment: Here is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757975/ios-soundtouch-framework-bpm-detection-example