# BPM detection in iOS using soundtouch library

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, soundtouch, beat-detection

I am trying to implement beatdetection within an iOS application. I found a fairly simple framework called SoundTouch and tried to implement this according to

[iOS SoundTouch framework BPM Detection example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757975/ios-soundtouch-framework-bpm-detection-example)

Unfortunately none of my following efforts seem to work and am currently in a deadlock state hence my post to Stackoverflow.

I took the following steps:

1. Create single-view-based project
2. Imported the
3. Renamed mainViewController.m to ViewController.mm to make it compatible with c++
4. Instructed the UIViewController class of the ViewController to conform to the AVFoundationPlayerDelegate protocols.
5. Copy/Pasted the solution @MrHappyAsthma posted to his question
6. Refactored

   ```
   player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:NULL];
   ```

to

```
    AVAudioPlayer *player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:NULL];
```

Now the compiler is complaining on:

```
soundtouch::SAMPLETYPE sampleBuffer[len]; (use of undeclared variable soundtouch)

soundtouch::BPMDetect BPM(player.numberOfChannels, [[player.settings valueForKey:@"AVSampleRateKey"] longValue]); (use of undeclared variable soundtouch)

BPM.inputSamples(sampleBuffer, len/player.numberOfChannels); (use of undeclared variable BPM)

NSLog(@"Beats Per Minute = %f", BPM.getBpm()); (use of undeclared variable BPM)
```

I think my knowledge on C++ isn't what it should be and the objects soundtouch and BPM should be declared/initialized.

Thanks folks!

Comment: it seems that you have not included sound touch headers -- although you say you did… could you not post some more code? even your full project somewhere…

Comment: Sure: http://www.ski-inndronten.nl/TestProject.zip

Comment: Thanks for the effort!

Comment: @AlexvanRijs: Don't forget to award the bountry (the little blue box under the green tick!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need do the following in order to compile th project:

1. add `#import <SoundTouch/BPMDetect.h>` to your `ViewController.mm`;
2. add AVFoundation framework to your target (see picture);
3. set the language settings as shown in picture (specifically, use GNU C++ libstdc++).

I haven't tried to run the program, but it builds at least.

[image]
[image]

Comment: That seemed to work! For what architectures do you have this project set? I have armv64 armv7 and armv7s. It wouldn't build on armv64 so I removed that one

Comment: I did not touch the architectures setting and I assume that it was only building for the current platform (debug mode), so I did not get the error. Possibly the issue lies with sound touch not being built for arm64...

Comment: Hi Sergio, when compiling and running the code the program exists on EXC_BAD_ACCESS on line: soundtouch::SAMPLETYPE sampleBuffer[len]. What could be the reason for this error. It only happens when running on the iphone. When running in the simulator it does not crash but the BPM is always 0.

Comment: @AlexvanRijs bpm always return 0 in soundtouch . please give me any idea how to resolve problem