# OSX equalizer for cocoa app

Tags: macos, equalizer

I want to create an Equalizer for a Cocoa app but I don't know much about OS X development. Looking for some build in framework or library or steps for create own equalizer for cocoa app.

I find one library https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP but it use it's own player but I need to do with default players like AVPlayer and AVAudioPlayer

Equalizer like this

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library project if it might help you. [Cocoa Waveform](https://github.com/gyetvan-andras/cocoa-waveform)

Also I found somewhat questions related to wave form are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398753/using-the-apple-fft-and-accelerate-framework?lq=1).